# Codeigniter dropdown menu with database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

first i'll try to explain my problem. I'm very new to codeigniter and i'm trying to make a drop down menu in codeigniter fetching results from database. I already made some experiences but doesn't work as it should.

first my model:

```
public function get_continents() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('continents');
    $this->db->order_by("continent_name", "asc");
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    }
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

public function get_contries() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('countries');
    $this->db->join('continents', 'country_continent_id = continent_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('continent_id', $id);
    $this->db->order_by('country_name', 'asc');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    }
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

now the controller:

```
public function index() {
    $dados['title'] = 'Places to Visit';
    $dados['page'] = 'home';

    // lista dos continentes
    $this->load->model('option_model');
    $dados['continent'] = $this->option_model->get_continents();

    // lista os paises
    $dados['country'] = $this->option_model->get_contries();

    // chamar a vista -> view
    $this->load->view('home', $dados);
}
```

and the view:

```
 <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" id="home">Homepage</a></li>
                <?php foreach ($continent as $row) {; ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" id="<?php echo $row->continent_id; ?>"><?php echo $row->continent_name; ?></a>
                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach($country as $row2) {; ?>
                                <li><a href="" id="<?php echo $row2->country_id; ?>"><?php echo $row2->country_name; ?></a></li>
                            <?php }; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>
                <li><a href="" id="pt">Portugal</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

What i want to make is a menu of continents and each continent has a drop down with the countries like this:

```
> continent 1
   - country 1
   - country 2
   - ...
> continent 2
   - country 1
   - country 2
   - ...
> ...
```

how can i do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the `get_continents()` function so that it append the **country** for each **continent**.

How to do this?

In `get_continents()`

```
public function get_continents() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('continents');
    $this->db->order_by("continent_name", "asc");
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {

        // Get Countries list for each continent
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {

            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('countries');
            $this->db->where('country_continent_id', $row->continent_id);
            $this->db->order_by('country_name', 'asc');
            $country = $this->db->get()->result();

            // append country to the continent object
            $row->country = $country;

        }

        return $query->result();

    }
    else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

In View:

```
 <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" id="home">Homepage</a></li>
                <?php foreach ($continent as $row) {; ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" id="<?php echo $row->continent_id; ?>"><?php echo $row->continent_name; ?></a>
                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach($row->country as $row2) {; ?>
                                <li><a href="" id="<?php echo $row2->country_id; ?>"><?php echo $row2->country_name; ?></a></li>
                            <?php }; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>
                <li><a href="" id="pt">Portugal</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

What we do is the following:

1. In the `get_continents` we append the **country** object to each of **continent** object.
2. In View, we replace `$country` in nested foreach loop with `$row->country`

Comment: THANK YOU =) was going for this but still need some help. tku, tku, tku...

Answer (score 0):

Your error is most probably from the function `get_contries()`
you have one line that has `$this->db->where('continent_id', $id);`

remove that line and you should be fine.

Comment: tks for your reply but in order to know the country continent shouldn't i have a variable for that? that is one of my problems. if i remove that line, i have no way to see what country belongs to what continent.

Comment: actually that line is not working at all, because you don't have a variable name `$id` so it will mess your query, if you want build it using json.

Comment: i know its not working. i have to pass a value to that variable but dont know how. my first guess is to join the 2 functions but as i said i'm new to codeigniter.

Comment: yes, you have to join the two functions in one function,it will take a bit of time from you, but it will save you fore sure.